# Akka: sending PoisonPill to Master vs terminating system context

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to decide between two different methods of shutting down my Akka actor system:

**Option #1: Send a `PoisonPill` to the `Master` (root-most User) actor:**

```
val master = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Master], name = "Master")

// Lots of code doing stuff

master ! PoisonPill
```

**Option #2: Create a custom `Shutdown` message and send to a custom `Killswitch` actor:**

```
case class Shutdown()

class Killswitch extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Shutdown =>
      context.system.terminate()
  }
}

val killswitch = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Killswitch], name = "Killswitch")

killswitch ! Shutdown
```

Are there any differences between these two approaches, or do they both result with the same exact end effect?

If they're truly identical solutions, I think I'm opting for #1 since its a wee bit less code for me to write. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the two:-

1)  PoisonPill will terminate the actor and stop the message queue. They will cause the actor to cease processing messages, send a stop call to all its children, wait for them to terminate, then call its postStop hook. All further messages are sent to the dead letters mailbox.

**Poison Pill does not shut down the actor system.**

Sending a PoisonPill, is simply another message in the queue, so the sequence will start when the PoisonPill is received. All messages that are ahead of it in the queue will be processed first.

Also see the 'Stopping an Actor', 'Killing an Actor' section in the docs:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html

2)  context.system.terminate() will terminate the whole actor system and not a single actor.

So Ideally you should use context.system.terminate() to terminate your actor system.

Answer (score 1):

No, they aren't identical at all.

1. The `PoisonPill` will be sent and enqueued in the `Master`s mailbox as an ordinary message. All messages sent to `Master` before the `PoisonPill` will be processed as usual. If the `Master` itself does not shutdown the entire `ActorSystem`, then the actor system will not be shut down, only the `Master` actor will. Note that this works even if `Master` is in a remote actor system.
2. This shuts down the current actor system. It prevents all actors from processing any further messages. This doesn't work with remote actor systems.

How your application will be shut down depends very much on the structure of your application.